# CHECK CONSTRAINT to validate a JSON field using a regular expression

Tags: json, postgresql, check-constraints

I know I can use a regular expression in a constraint to validate the contents of a field like

```
CONSTRAINT foo CHECK (column ~* 'regex')
```

I know I can do this even for a json column as I can grab specific attributes of it like

```
CONSTRAINT bar CHECK ((column->>'attribute')...
```

But is there any way to ensure that the json data as a whole matches a specific pattern? I mean if I have a field in which let's say only an object of key-value pairs is allowed, I mean this:

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

(keys with arbitrary names) Can I validate this with a constraint?

Comment: No, you should not use regex for that. Use the json functions to ensure that it's an object, and that all its property values are strings.

Comment: you could use this: https://github.com/gavinwahl/postgres-json-schema

Comment: so the only way to do this is to call a custom function inside the check constrain, right?

Comment: I doubt it is the only way, but I suspect every other way is worse.